# Como alterar código de upload de imagem para funcionar no mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

consegui esse código para upload de imagem para funcionar no PostgreSQL, mas gostaria de altera-lo para funcionar no phpMyAdmin, mas estou encontrando uma certa dificuldade, e gostaria de contar com a ajuda dos amigos.

O código esta assim:

```
//Instancia a clase passando o arquivo (atributo name no form).
$logo = "";
if (isset($_FILES["logo"]))
{
    $dir_dest = "../upload";
    $upload = new Upload($_FILES['logo'], $dir_dest);

// verifica se foi realizado corretamente o Upload
if ($upload->processed){
$logo = $upload->file_dst_name;
}
}

$objImagemlogo = new Imagemlogo();
$objImagemlogo->codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
$objImagemlogo->logo = $logo;
$objImagemlogo->atualizar();
?>
```

O nome no arquivo de upload é Upload.php.

Eu tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
   <form name="enter" method="post" action="Upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>Código:</label></br>
   <input type="number" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $res['codigo'];?>" readonly="readonly"></br>
   <label>Imagem Atual:</label></br>
   <img width="200" height="auto" src="../upload/<?php echo $res['logo'];?>"/></br>
   <label>Imagem:</label></br>
   <input type="file" name="logo" ></br>
   <input class="input" type="submit" name="enter" value="Atualizar" /></br>
   </form>
```

Achei que trazendo pelo action o arquivo Upload.php, funcionaria, mas me equivoquei. E agora não tenho ideia de como alterar o código para que possa funcionar no projeto em Mysql.

Se os amigos puderem me dar essa ajuda, ficarei agradecido.

Abraços à todos, e BRIGADÃO desde já.

Conforme solicitado segue abaixo todo conteúdo do arquivo query do objImagemlogo:

```
    <?php
    include_once 'BD.class.php';
    class Imagemlogo {
    private $codigo;
    private $logo;

    //variaveis internas
    private $bd; //conexão com o banco
    private $tabela; //nome da tabela

    public function __construct() {
    $this->bd = new BD();
    $this->tabela = "pagcabecalho";
    }
    public function __destruct() {
    unset($this->bd);
    }

    public function __get($key) {
    return $this->$key;
    }

    //método de retorno de valores do objeto 
    public function __set($key, $value) {
    $this->$key = $value;
    }

    public function listar($complemento = "") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->tabela ".
                    $complemento;

    $resultado = pg_query($sql);
    $retorno = NULL;
    //percorre os registros
    while ($reg = pg_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        //transforma em objetos produto
        $obj = new Imagemlogo();
        $obj->codigo = $reg["codigo"];
        $obj->logo = $reg["logo"];
        //adiciona a variavel de retorno
        $retorno[] = $obj;
    }
    return $retorno;
    }

    public function excluir() {

    $sql = "delete from $this->tabela where codigo=$this->codigo";
    $retorno = pg_query($sql);
    return $retorno;
    }

    public function retornarunico() {
    $sql = "Select * FROM $this->tabela where codigo=$this->codigo LIMIT 1";

    $resultado = pg_query($sql);
    $retorno = NULL;

    $req = pg_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    if ($req == true) {
        $obj = new Imagemlogo();
        $obj->codigo = $req["codigo"];
        $obj->logo = $req["logo"];

        $retorno = $obj;
    } else {
        $retorno = null;
    }

    return $retorno;
    }
    public function atualizar() {
    $retorno = false;
    $sql = "UPDATE $this->tabela SET logo='$this->logo' WHERE codigo=$this->codigo";
    $retorno = pg_query($sql);
    return $retorno;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Você precisa alterar a sua query, o upload continua sendo a mesma coisa, poderia postar a query que o objeto `$objImagemlogo` executa?

Comment: Olá Jeferson Assis, eu editei a mensagem com os dados do arquivo que se refere ao upload. Espero que seja isso que deseja! Desde já meus agradecimentos pela sua atenção.

Comment: Você precisa mudar a conexão e as funções que consultando no banco exemplo: `pg_query`, `pg_fetch_assoc` , entre as outras

Comment: Valeu Jeferson Assis, mas eu não tenho ideia de como efetuar tais alterações, você poderia me dar uma luz, pois sou leigo nesse tipo de arquivo, porém muito curioso. Abraços...